# How to convert date format from Y-m-d to d-m-Y?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to convert the  `date_of_birth` column's date format from `Y-m-d` to `d-m-Y`.
Below is my model:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Stock extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'tag_no';    
    public $incrementing = false;    
    protected $fillable = [        
        'tag_no',
        'stock_type',        
        'date_of_birth',                  
    ];

    protected $dates=[
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'date_of_birth'
    ];


    public function getDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value));
    }
}
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: Well the first question would be ... Does it work?

Comment: well..is there any other way to do it?

Comment: See this https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting{{ date('d-m-y', strtotime($post->date)) }}

Comment: {{ date('d-m-Y',strtotime('2018-5-2')) }} Output : 02-05-2018, it all depends on what you pass in the second parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $in = '2018-08-20';
    $out = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $in)->format('d-m-Y');
    print_r($out); // 20-08-2018
```

Comment: I actually want to store the date as d-m-Y format... can this be used to store it in that way?

Comment: you can directly use `(new DateTime($in))->format('d-m-Y');`

Comment: inside my store function?

Comment: You dont want to store a date on the database in anything other than `Y-m-d` format. Thats the format what MySQL expects a date to be saved in. But there is no reason you cannot reformat that date to suit your users preference, but do that in the presentation layer